# No Such Module like Sqlite in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, xcode8

i was making a project using sqlite in swift. I added Sqlite manually to my project like told in this tutorial
[This link under Manual method](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#joining-other-tables)

So it compiled and worked fine with my mac. But when i transferred it to other one and compiled then it said No Such Module.
[image: See the image for error]

But again when i manually added the framework to my xcode project in the other computer, it started working. Can you tell me how can i do it like that it does not need to be added again and again.

Comment: How are you transferring between computers?

Comment: I uploaded the file to the dropbox and downloaded at the other.

Comment: You need all of the files, not just the swift file.  Did you bring over the project files as well?

Comment: No, i did not. in the link, it only says to import the workspace file only.

Answer (score 1):

It took some time but here is the answer:
1. Need to download the file sqlite.swift-master.zip
[Downlod from here](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/archive/master.zip)
2. Unzip it and drag the SQLite.xcodeproj file into your own project.
3. In your target’s General tab, click the + button under Linked Frameworks and Libraries, add the sqlite framework for ios and in the Embedded Binaries the sqlite.framework.

Here is a nice video that helps:
[Youtube video](https://youtu.be/c4wLS9py1rU)

Answer (score 0):

This would be a great use of git for transferring between computers that way you can avoid issues like this and you will have less chance of losing work that started on one computer but forgot to transfer it to other computer.

Best practice would be to commit on major changes in code or if you are not going to be working on the code for an extend time frame. Or when you know that you need to transfer to another computer.

I use bitbucket because it allows unlimited private repositories. If you are going to do a file level copy you should always copy the full folder.

Comment: i used Cocoapods to install the pods file but it failed so i used the manual way to do it.

Comment: Even if you use pods as long as you add the files to the git then you should avoid the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change your deployment target of your **Project** and your **Target** to IOS 11. That should do it. Also, make sure that the swift_version of all your targets is set to **Swift 4**.